# AngularJS trying to add a class to multiple values if it is true on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am having a hard time finding any resources on this matter and I was hoping somebody could help me.

I am currently pulling information from a DB and using AngularJS to do a ng-repeat based on specific filters.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

Based on this I am trying to add a class to change the background of {{data.status}} based on what is returned.  Could I possibly get an example of

```
 if data.status=="TEST" then add class "alert-success"
 else if data.status=="NEW" then add class "alert-info"
 else if data.status=="JUNK" then add class "alert-danger"
 else ""
```

and so on.  Thank you ahead of time.

Just so you can see what my current controller looks like

```
app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http.get('ajax/test.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.list = data;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 100; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
});
$scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
};
$scope.filter = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    }, 10);
};
$scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS comes with a built-in directive called **[ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**, which does exactly what you are looking for. Applied to your example request:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td ng-class=" { 'alert-success': data.status=='TEST', 'alert-info': data.status=='NEW', 'alert-danger': data.status=='JUNK' } ">{{data.status}}</td
</tr>
```

Comment: Your code got me to the right place.  Please update your ng-class to have brackets that was necessary for the code and I will put it as the solution.  Thank you for your help.